# По какой логике выбирается метка, помещаемая в заголовок страницы с вопросом?

Tags: поддержка, метки, заголовок

Я вот тут [накатал перевод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/986136) и прописал в метках пачку терминов, упоминаемых в переведённом тексте. При этом в заголовке страницы оказалась метка [png] — наименее релевантная из всех перечисленных. Почему? Ладно, слова из некоторых других меток уже упомянуты в заголовке и их дублировать не стоит — но почему не [сжатие], например?

Comment: Исключаются все теги, что присутствуют в тексте заголовка и из оставшихся выбирается наиболее популярный (количество вопросов на этой метке?)

Comment: @АндрейNOP если по количеству, то была бы метка [tag:zip].

Comment: @Suvitruf, zip в тексте заголовка уже есть. То что я написал – не сам выдумал, а прочитал где-то здесь на мете или в справке.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Логика

Как [@Андрей NOP](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop) уже написал в комментарии, исключаются все теги, что присутствуют в тексте заголовка и из оставшихся выбирается наиболее популярный

Об этом пишет [@Adam Lear♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear) на Meta.SE ([How is the page title tag determined [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180384)):

> Usually the tag included in the title is [...] the top tag on the question. However, we try not to duplicate information more than absolutely necessary, so we don't bother prepending the tag name when it's already used in the title elsewhere.
>
> In this case, [...] we move on to the next most prominent tag. [...] If there were no other tags, the question title would be tag-less altogether.
>
> ***Грубый перевод:***
>
> *Обычно в заголовок помещается первая метка из вопроса. Но, т.к. мы стараемся не дублировать информацию без крайней на то необходимости, мы не добавляем метку, если она уже используется где-то в заголовке.*
>
> *В этом случае, мы переходим к следующей метке. Если больше меток нет, то метка в заголовок не добавляется.*

Метки по вопросу упорядочены в порядке убывания количества вопросов, по которым проставлена метка (см. [Tag order by frequency](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148176)).

### Пример

Количество вопросов по каждой метке в Вашем примере:

- [zip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip) — 124;
- [png](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/png) — 78;
- [gzip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gzip) — 41;
- [сжатие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5) — 33;
- [zlib](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zlib) — 6.

Т.к. [zip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip) указана в заголовке, получаем что [png](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/png) — самая популярная метка из неуказанных.

Пути решения:

- убрать [png](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/png), вроде она не особо там нужна ([в оригинальном вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094/how-are-zlib-gzip-and-zip-related-what-do-they-have-in-common-and-how-are-they/20765054#20765054) ее нет);
- как-нибудь включить [png](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/png) в заголовок;
- ничего не делать, не так уж и страшно, что в заголовке [png](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/png).

Comment: «в оригинальном вопросе ее нет» — и мне кажется, что это неправильно, так как png имеет непосредственное отношение к истории zlib. Наверно, воспользуюсь последним путём решения)

Comment: Возможно, стоит проверить еще и на русскоязычных метках.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Не совсем понятно что происходит при частичном совпадении. Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936504) метка попала в заголовок во второй раз. А так, в общем вроде, работает, вот примеры, когда пропускаются: [первая метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/933139), [все метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/942822)